# No pagination support found in Quartz scheduler on Quartz_job_schedule table

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I was thinking about the architecture to implement Quartz scheduler in my application to schedule jobs. I have angular table where i am showing all jobs from database table QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS. But **No pagination support found** in API. I searched in **StdJDBCDelegate.java** class too.
I am using spring boot 2.1.7 and Quartz 2.3.1

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
```

Can anyone suggest how can i achieve pagination on Quartz tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Correct Anurag, ***no API support available***. Alternatively i created a hibernate entity pojo class which contains id, jobName and other relevant private variables & getters/setters. Then passed this pojo to one of my JPARepository. Now there would be a database table lets say ***custom_job_detais***. This way there was duplicacy of data stored in database but it was workaround actually.

Jobname column stored into both the tables would remain same. For frontend pagination purpose we can use  ***custom_job_detais*** and for job management ***QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS*** table will be used.

Save data into ***custom_job_detais*** table before saving into ***QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS***. Now easily we can implement pagination support on ***custom_job_detais*** table rather than ***QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS***.

-Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Quartz provides any API for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a page response for quartz jobs or triggers, either they can create pojo and retrieve the data directly from the whatever the JobStore DB

or

can use spring Pageable and/or PagedListHolder implementation to create PageImpl from List and return.

My Code example to get all group jobs is as follows,

```
 public SchedulerResponse findAllJobs(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

        SchedulerResponse responseBean = new SchedulerResponse();

        List<JobDetailRequestBean> jobDetailRequestBeanList= new ArrayList<>();

        PagedListHolder<JobDetailRequestBean> jobDetailRequestBeanPLH = new PagedListHolder<>();

        try {
            for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
                for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
                    String jobName = jobKey.getName();
                    String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();
                    //get job's trigger
                    List<Trigger> triggers = (List<Trigger>) scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
                    JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey(jobName, jobGroup));
                    if(Objects.nonNull(jobDetail)) {
                        JobDetailRequestBean jobDetailRequestBean =JobDetailRequestBean.buildJobDetail(
                                        jobDetail, triggers);
                        if(Objects.nonNull(jobDetailRequestBean))
                            jobDetailRequestBeanList.add(jobDetailRequestBean);
                    }
                }
            }
            jobDetailRequestBeanPLH.setSource(jobDetailRequestBeanList);
            jobDetailRequestBeanPLH.setPageSize(pageSize);
            jobDetailRequestBeanPLH.setPage(pageNumber);
            responseBean.setResult(new PageImpl<>(jobDetailRequestBeanPLH.getPageList(), pageable, jobDetailRequestBeanList.size()));
            responseBean.setResultCode(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseBean.setResultCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            responseBean.setResult(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return responseBean;
    }
```